# Passing a python list to keras model.fit

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

So right now I'm using keras and training my model works perfectly fine, but I have to pass my data as numpy ndarray. So I have to convert my list of data to numpy ndarray first and then pass it to keras for training. When I try to pass my python list/array, even tho it's the same shape as numpy array I get back errors. Is there any way to not use numpy for this or am I stuck with it?

Answer (score 2):

Can you further explain your problem. What is the error message you are getting and are you getting this error during training or predicting?

Also if you could post some code samples that would help to

Comment: `ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 431 arrays` this is the error message that I'm getting. Now if I just convert this list of arrays to numpy array like this `numpy.array(my_list)` the error goes away. This is the only place in the whole application where I use numpy, so I just wanna remove the dependency if I use it in one place

Comment: @DuškoMirković You may want to provide some more information about your project, such as the definition of your model and the lines in which you call the `model.fit` method. Since keras accepts array-like objects as input, you may have bugs in your code.

Comment: My pyhon list `shape` is like this `[n, 50, 6]`, and when I pass that list as parameter to `model.fit` it does not work, I get the error message from previous comment. Now if I do `training_data = np.array(python_list)` I have the same `shape = [n, 50, 6]` but for some reason `model.fit` is working.